# jquery mobile toPage select attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a jquery mobile app with some pages. the first page is a login page and after the user logged in i dont want the user to go back to the login page again.

after the user logged in a `div` called #map will be shown.

to prevent this is have the following code:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainerbeforechange', function (e, ui) {

    var activePage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage');

    if(activePage.attr('id') === 'map') {

        var test = ui.toPage;

        console.log(test.attr('id');

        // if(test.attr('id') === 'login' && login.status === true) {
        //  console.log('you are alrady logged in');
        //  e.preventDefault();
        //  e.stopPropagation();
        // }
    }
});
```

When i click previous page to go to the login page again i get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: test.attr is not a function`

What is wrong and how can i select the `attr` id of test

Comment: toPage API Doc:  This property represents the page the caller wishes to make active. It can be either a jQuery collection object containing the page DOM element, or an absolute/relative url to an internal or external page. The value exactly matches the 1st arg to the changePage() call that triggered the event.  Console.log the ui.toPage to see what it is...

Comment: Hi, it gives me a jquery object just as i would select it like this $('#login').attr('id'); but test.attr('id') gives me a error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the ui.toPage is a string and sometimes it is a jQuery object representing the page. Sometimes the pagecontainerbeforechange runs twice, once with the string and once with the object. So try this:

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainerbeforechange", function( e, ui ) {
    var from = ui.prevPage ? ui.prevPage.prop("id") : '';
    var to = '';
    if (typeof ui.toPage === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(ui.toPage);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);
    } else {
        to = '#' + ui.toPage.prop("id");
    }

  if (from === 'map' && to === '#login') {
      alert('Cannot change to login from map');
      e.preventDefault();
           // remove active class on button
            // otherwise button would remain highlighted
      $.mobile.activePage
                .find('.ui-btn-active')
                .removeClass('ui-btn-active');
   }                
});
```

## **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/jrkkvN)**

Also, .attr("id") will work, but in newer versions of jQuery it is more correct to use .prop("id"): http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Hi, thank you this seems to work, but if i click the back button in the browser twice it reloads the page and all my ajax data is gone then. any idea ?